# How to route inside .ejs file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Is there is any way to use route function inside the front-end, something like `href="<%= route("add_agent") %>` instead of using `href="./add_agent"`

```
<a href="./add_agent">Add Agent</a>
<a href="./edit_agents">Edit/Delete Agent</a>
<a href="./all_admins">All Admins</a>
<a href="./add_admin">Add Admin</a>
```

Just to let you know, I am using NodeJs (express framework) with ejs views.